# auto fill sign up data in custom form Magento 2 frontend

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.3, magento2.2, magento2.1

Someone please suggest the solution?

I want prefilled data in my custom form that user already entered in the signup form.

Thanks,
Rashi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the customer's local storage.
Long story, thus you can check this [blog](https://belvg.com/blog/customer-data-management-in-magento-2.html) for more information.

When we've got the `customerData` from the `Magento_Customer/js/customer-data.js`  source, you can fill the form with it. `$('#custom-form-username').val(customerData.get('name'));` . I hope this will give you some directions.